# Horizontal Scrollbar Generated on Vertical scrollbar Overflow

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I'm working in a large legacy system with thousands of pages where dynamically generated tabular data is populated into html defined in the following format:

```
<table style="border: 2px solid blue;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="overflow: auto; border: 2px solid orange; height: 200px;">
                <table style="border: 2px solid green;">
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've been tasked with removing unnecessary small horizontal scrollbars that seemingly riddle the system.  After a while of examining the issue I realized that when the amount of tabular data vertically overflows the containing div and causes the vertical scrollbar to appear, the newly generated vertical scrollbar is itself pushing into the div's content area and thus causes the tabular data to overflow horizontally, thereby causing the undesired horizontal scrollbars that are appearing.  In other words, when the vertical scrollbar appears it intrudes into the content space and thus causes the horizontal scrollbar to appear.  This can be intuited by the fact that, no matter the width of the scrollable div, the horizontal scrollbars scrollable space is precisely the width of the vertical scrollbar.

My questions are:

1)  Is this a browser issue?  I tested this on Firefox and Chrome and found the issue in both, but when I tested on a version of IE (don't remember which, it was at work) it didn't seem to happen at all.

2)  Is there an elegant best practices method to resolve this issue?  I found that adding about 20px padding to the right side of the div gets rid of the issue by giving the scrollbar enough breathing room to push into, but of course when the table isn't populated with enough data to cause overflow the padding still remains as an unsightly 20px whitespace gap.  There seem to be a lot of similar ways to address the issue (like adding an empty table column the width of the scrollbar, setting overflow-y:scroll which causes there to ALWAYS be a vertical scrollbar, or setting a hardcoded width on the outer table), but they all seem to have their own advantages and disadvantages.  Ultimately I wrote a javascript function that onload adds padding to the inner table whenever there's a vertical scrollbar, but it really seems like overkill to me for an issue I don't think should even be happening in the first place.

UPDATE:
1)  I need to keep the ability to overflow on the y axis.  There is other data on the page besides the tables, so the tables need to be vertically scrollable whenever too much data is generated for them.  However, this of courses the horizontal scroll problem.

Comment: I don't think it is the issue here but, why use this div? why not put the properties on the td? EDIT: it was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a padding-right:20px; seems to do the trick for me on firefox

```
<table style="border: 2px solid blue;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="overflow: auto; border: 2px solid orange; height: 200px;">
                <table style="border: 2px solid green;">
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td><td>testingtext</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This seems to cause all the scrollbars to disappear, not just the horizontal scrollbar.  Unfortunately, I need for the tabular data to be vertically scrollbar whenever there's too many data items for the viewable region.  Other functionality exists on these pages besides these tables, so the tables are constrained in height to their own region on the pages.  It would be nice if I could simply say overflow-x:hidden, but then whenever the tabular data happens to be really, really long the data winds up being hidden when it overflows on the x.

Comment: I noted in my original post that adding 20px resolves the issue but it's only really a temporary bandaid, because when the table isn't filled with enough data to overflow then you're left with a 20px gap on the side of your table where the vertical scrollbar would be.  Since in my use case the data is dynamically generated, I'm looking for a solution that works when there's little/no data in the table or when there's a lot.  It can be done with Javascript that conditionally adds padding depending on whether there's a vertical scrollbar or not, but it seems like overkill to me.